# Nimbus not compatible with iOS 4.3 using cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, nimbus, cocoapods

when I try to use [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/) to install [Nimbus](http://nimbuskit.info/) i get the following error: `[!] Nimbus (1.0.0) is not compatible with iOS 4.3.`

I'm not sure where this iOS 4.3 came from.. but here are some more details:

my Podfile content:

```
platform :ios

pod 'AFNetworking', '0.9.1'

pod 'SSToolkit'
pod 'ConciseKit'
pod 'Nimbus'
```

when I run `pod install` I get:

```
warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Resolving dependencies of `./Podfile'
Updating spec repositories

Cocoapods 0.17.0.rc1 is available.

Resolving dependencies for target `default' (iOS 4.3)
[!] Nimbus (1.0.0) is not compatible with iOS 4.3.
```

ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you dont define an iOS version, 4.3 is assumed as the default by cocoapods

For example if you define the Podfile as follow `platform :ios, '5.0'` the minimum iOS version for your porject will be 5.0

In your case it means that Nimbus has a higher iOS version number defined to be the minimum in their podspec. Depending on your project minimum target either update your Podfile to support a higher version or check if previous versions of Nimbus are compatible with ios 4.3

for defining a specific version for a pod use `pod 'Nimbus', '0.X.Y'` where X and Y are the version numbers

Comment: This has changed in Cocoapods `0.17rc1` which can be installed with `gem install cocoapods --pre` which takes your project's default version for use instead.

Comment: My symptom of this was the following error: The platform of the target `Pods` (iOS 4.3) is not compatible with `AFNetworking (2.0.0)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 6.0 - OS X 10.8.

Answer (score -1):

In your pod file replace platform :ios with platform :ios,'7.1'